# Log TLS/SSL handshake between client and server programmatically with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, cfnetwork

I want to be able to look at the TLS handshake information programmatically, and be able to do something like this:

```
NSLog(@"Client Hello");
//...
NSLog(@"Server Hello");
```

There's a good [blog post](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) showing said handshake information in greater detail (or see the wireshark capture image below).

I'm already using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), so the code samples below are taken from that code base. I would however, seriously consider switching to the more modern [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library if logging TLS handshake information is possible with it. I believe AFNetworking uses different objects (i.e. NSURLConnection, NSURLCredential).

I'm adding a SecIdentityRef to the stream ([view more code context](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.m#L1243)).

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, sslProperties);
```

I'm listing to the following network events:

```
static const CFOptionFlags kNetworkEvents = kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted | kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes | kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred;
```

This events are described in the [CFStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html) portion of the documentation.

This is how the stream is opened ([view more code context](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.m#L1389)):

```
CFStreamClientContext ctxt = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
if (CFReadStreamSetClient((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kNetworkEvents, ReadStreamClientCallBack, &ctxt)) {
    if (CFReadStreamOpen((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream])) {
        streamSuccessfullyOpened = YES;
    }
}
```

A switch statement is used when the callback (`ReadStreamClientCallBack`) gets called to handle the events:

```
switch (type) {
    case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        //...
        break;

    case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
        //...
        break;

    //other events here...

    default:
        break;
}
```

I believe the handshake happens between: `kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted` and `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`.

Following the instructions [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/02/07/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices.html) I was able to capture and analyze packets from/to an iPhone and Server using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

[image: Wireshark Capture Picture]

Is there any API I can call or library I can use to get similar information on the device?